# Added Dropdown Menu in _layout, now 2 of the top nav items are overlapping

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, model-view-controller, razor

I added a Dropdown menu to my asp.net core mvc project to change between Crypto/Encrypt and Crypto/Decrypt. The CurveSample Button and Crypto Dropdown are now overlapping, as if they are both using the same space. I've already tried to add margin and padding, but to no success so far. The _layout is using the provided layout.css

_layout.cshtml part of navbar:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">AnotherTechblog</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="CurveSample">Curve Sample</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark" href="#" id="cryptoDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Crypto
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="cryptoDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="" asp-controller="Encryption" asp-action="EncryptCipher">Encrypt Text</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="" asp-controller="Decryption" asp-action="DecryptCipher">Decrypt Cipher</a>  
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="WordCount" asp-action="WordCount">Wiki Wordcounter</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

layout.css

```
html {
    font-size: 14px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    html {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

/* Dropdown menu */
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}

    .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100px;
        padding: 80px 200px;
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 20px;
        clear: both;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #333;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

        .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
        .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            color: #262626;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:before {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: "";
    border-top: 4px solid;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}

.dropdown.open:before {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 4px solid;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
```